# Salesforce databasedotcom gem: Query doesn't return right results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, salesforce

I'm currently using the databasedotcom gem to authenticate and connect to Salesforce. So a user on my app signs in to salesforce and then I can show their organization Users by materializing the User table and doing SF::User.all.

Now, this works, but sometimes, it returns another users details.

The authentication token is mine at all times though.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a very similar issue using Twitter and Oauth. Are you using a global configuration of some sort? Check out the Thread safety section here: https://github.com/sferik/twitter#thread-safety I think it might be relevant.